# How do I recognize someone navigated to my app?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

Is there a specific function which is called when someone navigates from the home screen to my app again?

In my application i'm requesting data from a server and i don't want it to be requested everytime someone navigates to my app. The request should come at a maximum of once in an hour. Would a timer keep running when i go from the app to the start screen, or would it stop or keep it's state at maybe 58 minutes?

I'm using c# Windows Phone 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wish to make a request once an hour maximum, you could simply save the result with a `DateTime` to evaluate if the request can be made again or not, regardless of the navigation state, but if you really need to know, you can go to the `App.xaml` code-behind. There, you will find some methods that are useful.

The `Application_Launching` method is called only when the app starts for the first time. It will not be executed after that. Otherwise, if someone left your application and comes back later, the `Application_Activated` method will be called.

I also suggest you consult this [diagram displaying a Windows Phone app lifetime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff817008%28v=vs.105%29.aspx#AP_Con_ExecutionModel). The page describes the diagram and gives additional insights.